# multiline eqnarray, but only one equation number

Tags: numbering, eqnarray

I want to build an array and refer to it as with equations. The array consists on two lines; however, I would like to refer it as only one.
My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
As shown in Equation \ref{eq:2} ...

\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:2}
    H_0: \ h(\mathbf{X}) = 0 \\
    H_1: \ h(\mathbf{X}) \neq 0
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

I get two equation numbers -- one for each line. An alternative object type or any possible solution in order to get the formula in two lines but with only one equation number?

Comment: (1) as always on this site please post a full minimal example, not sniplets, that makes it a lot easier for others to test your code and provide solutions. (2) Never use `eqnarray` it is a broken construction (lucky for you not in this case), use `amsmath` and the envs in it. The manual for `amsmath` will tell you how to remove a single eqn number,  or, perhaps better, how to add a single centered eq no to a two line alignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with use of the package `amsmath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\begin{aligned}
    H_0\colon &\quad h(\mathbf{X}) = 0 \\
    H_1\colon &\quad h(\mathbf{X}) \neq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

note:

- `eqnarray` is deprecated for long time. rather use math environments provided by the package `amsmath`
- in the case, that you like to have equation centered (and not aligned to aligned at for example `:`), than instead of `aligned` you should use `gathered` (as suggested [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in his comment below):

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}\label{eq:2}
    H_0\colon\quad h(\mathbf{X}) = 0 \\
    H_1\colon\quad h(\mathbf{X}) \neq 0
\end{gathered}
```

(in your case since of equation has equal width the result is the same as before).

**edit:**
the package `amsmath` define also options for placement of equation numbers at `aligned` ans `gathered` math environments (as pointed [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard)). for example at `gathered` we can write and obtain:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}[t]\label{eq:2}
    H_0\colon\quad h(\mathbf{X}) = 0 \\
    H_1\colon\quad h(\mathbf{X}) \neq 0
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}[b]\label{eq:2}
    H_0\colon\quad h(\mathbf{X}) = 0 \\
    H_1\colon\quad h(\mathbf{X}) \neq 0
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

for more options and details for the package `amsmath` please read its documentation. it is part of any `latex` installation. also it is worth to read documentation for the package `mathtools` which is extension of `amsmath`.

[image]

Comment: +1. You may also want to mention the `gathered` environment, in case the OP doesn't need to (or want to) perform any horizontal alignment across rows.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much. i edit answer accordingly :-)

Comment: Fine, @Zarko! I'll remove my now useless comments

Answer (score 2):

You have two alignment points to take care of (even if the result would be the same with `gathered` because of the actual data).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

As shown in Equation~\ref{eq:notfavorite}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:notfavorite}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&H_0\colon &\  h(\mathbf{X}) &= 0 \\
&H_1\colon &\  h(\mathbf{X}) &\neq 0
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
and in Equation~\ref{eq:favorite}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:favorite}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&H_0\colon &  h(\mathbf{X}) &= 0 \\
&H_1\colon &  h(\mathbf{X}) &\neq 0
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note the `~` between `Equation` and `\ref`. I'd prefer the second, with no added space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        \begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:2}
          H_0: \ h(\mathbf{X}) = 0 \\\nonumber
           H_1: \ h(\mathbf{X}) \neq 0
             \end{eqnarray}
```

Here we get the number on the upper line. No number at the bottom line